# upload an eclipse android library project to maven central

Tags: gradle, android-library, aar, maven-central

background 
I have been building a android library project in eclipse..it originally does not get built with gradle and follows the old android folder structure

now in order to upload it to maven cental 
I first made an account at sonatype , then created an issue at jira for a new project .
They created a repo for my groupid com.github.amansatija , (for which i had wait two business days until issue was resolved )

now I created gpg key pair ring

after which i exported the eclipse android library project with gradle 
then i imported it in androistudio just to make sure it has become completely gradle friendly ..
now after the android library project's build system was changed to gradle i followed chris banes maven-push gradle plugin on github to deploy my library project on maven

below are the details of gradle my system

my global gradle.properties file (the one at user_homer.gradle\gradle.properties)
contains this

```
NEXUS_USERNAME=amansatija
NEXUS_PASSWORD=mushROOM@7

signing.keyId=16DF7223
signing.password=customer360
signing.secretKeyRingFile=mitul_private_key.gpg
```

my project's 
gradle.properties conatins this

```
VERSION_NAME=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
VERSION_CODE=1
GROUP=com.github.amanasatija

POM_DESCRIPTION=A demo test lib to understand maven central uploads
POM_URL=https://github.com/amansatija/Cus360MavenCentralDemoLib
POM_SCM_URL=https://github.com/amansatija/Cus360MavenCentralDemoLib
POM_SCM_CONNECTION==https://github.com/amansatija/Cus360MavenCentralDemoLib.git
POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION==https://github.com/amansatija/Cus360MavenCentralDemoLib.git
POM_LICENCE_NAME=The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
POM_LICENCE_URL=http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
POM_LICENCE_DIST=repo
POM_DEVELOPER_ID=amansatija
POM_DEVELOPER_NAME=Aman Satija
```

my project's maven_push file contains the following

```
/*
 * Copyright 2013 Chris Banes
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def isReleaseBuild() {
    return VERSION_NAME.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
}

def getReleaseRepositoryUrl() {
    return hasProperty('RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL') ? RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL
            : "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
}

def getSnapshotRepositoryUrl() {
    return hasProperty('SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL') ? SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL
            : "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
}

def getRepositoryUsername() {
    return hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
}

def getRepositoryPassword() {
println(NEXUS_PASSWORD)
println(NEXUS_USERNAME)
    return hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

                pom.groupId = GROUP
                pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
                pom.version = VERSION_NAME

                repository(url: getReleaseRepositoryUrl()) {
                    authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
                }
                snapshotRepository(url: getSnapshotRepositoryUrl()) {
                    authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
                }

                pom.project {
                    name POM_NAME
                    packaging POM_PACKAGING
                    description POM_DESCRIPTION
                    url POM_URL

                    scm {
                        url POM_SCM_URL
                        connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
                        developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
                    }

                    licenses {
                        license {
                            name POM_LICENCE_NAME
                            url POM_LICENCE_URL
                            distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
                        }
                    }

                    developers {
                        developer {
                            id POM_DEVELOPER_ID
                            name POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    signing {

        required { isReleaseBuild() && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
        sign configurations.archives
    }

    task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    }

    task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
    }

    task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
    }

    artifacts {
        archives androidSourcesJar
        archives androidJavadocsJar
    }
}
```

as you can see i have it print the nexus username and password and the script seems to have found the credentials properly

below is my lib module's build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

            // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
            instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

            // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
            // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
            // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
            // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
            // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
            // by a similar customization.
            debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
            release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        }
    }

apply from: '../maven_push.gradle'
```

also below is my library module's gradle.properties file

```
POM_NAME=DemoLibMavenCentral
POM_ARTIFACT_ID=DemoLibMavenCentral
POM_PACKAGING=aar
```

as you see I have followed the turoial appropriately 
 however when I do gradlew clean uploadArchives task ,,
everything goes smoothly except for the last step where it says failed 
Access denied

```
What went wrong:Execution failed for task ':DemoLibManvenCentral:uploadArchives'.Could not publish configuration 'archives'
Error deploying artifact 'com.github.amanasatija:library:apk': 
Error deploying artifact: Authorization failed: Access denied to: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/amanasatija/library/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/library-0.0.1-20141114.123550-1.apk
```

Help me out ...please ...

**Edit**

**Solution::**

So I finally managed to solve the issue.
Apparently the problem was

```
VERSION_NAME=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

in my project's gradle.properties file 
when i changed the above line to the following

```
VERSION_NAME=0.0.1
```

it worked seems to have worked properly ..
The tag SNAPSHOT was causing my artifacts to be deployed to snapshot repo of snotype , and the snapshot repo for some reason apprently it seems does not wat your artifacts , i guess it just wants pics or snapshots of your application

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have permissions to publish artifacts for the com.github.amanasatija group ID on the server.

File an issue for this at https://issues.sonatype.org under the "Community Support - Open Source Project Repository Hosting" project and we'll help you get this sorted out.

Comment: I Aksed the sonatype suppor to check the permission, He says access denied happens when invalid parameters are passed.. I don't see why shoudl there be invalid parametrs except for one thing when i look in the build folder i see only apk and no arr file please help me